# Double vim-surround with *

Tags: vim

Suppose my cursor is within the word `word`.  Using vim-surround, typing the sequence `ysiw*` will replace `word` with `*word*`.

**Question:** Is there a single sequence I can type to instead produce `**word**` (i.e., the common markdown method for word bolding)?  This opposed to typing `ysiw*` twice, which feels cumbersome.

Comment: Are you opposed to just recording a macro and executing it (where executing it requires exactly two keystrokes)?

Comment: For quick bolding of words, I developed the [Vim Markup Assistant](https://github.com/RubenVerborgh/vim-markup-assistant) plugin, which toggles bold with a simple press of F8. I might seem like overkill to solve this with an entire plugin, but I found myself needing it so often that it is a real time-saver as opposed to `ysiwb` or similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Dan Lowe's answer about using [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) and `.` is spot on. However you can also create custom surrounding to make common actions a bit quicker.

Add the following to your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` file:

```
let b:surround_{char2nr('b')} = "**\r**"
```

Now you can do `ysiwb` to surround with double `*`'s (`b` for bold).

For more help customizing surroundings see `:h surround-customizing`.

Comment: Good suggestion... funny enough I found this in my own Vim setup when I looked, but not quite like you show it (see my updated answer if interested in how to do it in `.vimrc` directly).

Answer (score 5):

Install the [vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) plugin and then you can do this with `.` (the repeat operator).

You would need to probably use `ysiw*l.` here, because (at least, when I tested) surround.vim leaves the cursor on the first surrounding character, so you have to move back into the word to do a repeat of the last surround. Otherwise you end up with `***word*`.

**Update:** Amusingly, after reading Peter Rincker's answer which mentions this answer, I found what he suggested was in my own Vim setup. But I didn't put it in an after file, mine is directly in `.vimrc`, like this:

```
autocmd FileType markdown,octopress let b:surround_{char2nr('i')} = "*\r*"
autocmd FileType markdown,octopress let b:surround_{char2nr('b')} = "**\r**"
```

Comment: This works as you mentioned; however, it fails to work if you select a visual block (in visual mode) and surround that visual block with *'s.

Comment: Well, vim repeats are not exactly consistent when used with visual blocks, so not too surprising...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do arbitrary manipulations and repeat them, the best way is with a vim macro.

For example, to repeat the action in the question, assuming it is generically repeatable, one can do the following to record the macro in the register `q`.

```
qqysiw*q
```

And then use the following the replay it for the second instance.

```
@q
```

Alternately, if you wanted a single macro to do double-surround, one possible way would just to be record the sequence twice in one macro.

```
 qqysiw*ysiw*q
```

Answer (score 0):

With [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets), in markdown documents, you could type `_` twice on the current word in normal mode -- which produces the same result in markdown once rendered. You could also type `\*` twice, but it's a little bit more cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

As a slightly different approach, We can define new commands:

1) a visual area boldifier command, ex:

```
:vmap \q di****<ESC>hP
```

(delete visual area, insert "****", put it back in the middle). Use it like `ve\q`.

2) a insert-mode command to boldify last written word:

```
:imap \q <ESC>diwi****<ESC>hPlla
```

3) a normal-mode boldify word under cursor:

```
:map \q diwi****<ESC>hP
```